# Snowflake connectivity with GIT

Tags: github, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way we can connect snowflake with GIT for version control. With the help of that, we can maintain version of our merge statement and any other sql script in GIT.

Comment: I believe Snowflake's new worksheet UI Snowsight is supposed to get native Git integration in the future. But for now, we are storing all our objects in Git and using [Redgate's Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/snowflake) to migrate the code to multiple environments through Azure DevOps. It works really well for us.

Comment: This post is over 3 years old so I'll point out that there is now a tool called schemachange (https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange) which is specific to Snowflake, provided (though not supported) by Snowflake Labs, and is heavily influenced by Flyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!  One way to do this is to store your `Snowflake SQL` code in a file/files with the `sql` extension (i.e. `filename.sql`). You can add those files to a `GIT` repo and track them in the repo accordingly.

Comment: Any other way where we can directly integrate snowflake with GIT

Comment: It's a fairly popular feature request you can upvote here (search on GIT): https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas


Although it's not a GIT integration, you might also try Snowsight, which is a Snowflake feature in Public Preview and may meet some of your needs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight.html

Answer (score 2):

There is now a VSCode extension for Snowflake. I'm able to connect vscode to our repo (Azure DevOps in my case) and Snowflake. It's got some nice features too like being able to easily cycle through past queries (including query results) and gives the same level of detail (or more) than the Snowflake UI.

The extension is called Snowflake - from Snowflake.

Comment: Please add the name of the extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

`DBeaver` has git integration and is the best solution my team has found for version control with Snowflake. It's not perfect but it allows you to run your scripts against Snowflake and then push your SQL code to a git repository through the app UI or command line.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers help with using an IDE as a go-between for git and Snowflake.  These projects could be useful also:

https://medium.com/snowflake/snowflake-vs-code-sql-tools-and-github-7eab915e10cb

- use VSCode as the IDE with a useful snowflake extension

https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/schemachange

- manage schema changes as script in git, deploy them with CI/CD

https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions#get-sfworksheets

- the missing feature of SnowSight -- export worksheets

Answer (score 0):

This is an age old question when dealing with databases and how one should go about versioning them. Unfortunately, no database really integrates directly into any VCS that I'm aware of.

My team has settled on using [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/). This essentially turns the database into a series of text files that are easily integrated with git. The short of it is that you edit your models as local text files, and then use `dbt run` to put these models into Snowflake itself. This is kind of nice as you can configure separate environments such as dev and prod.